# Change all rows for one column in Parse and setting an Object ID in DataBrowser

Tags: ios, parse-platform

So I have a button that will be hidden on my app. However one day that I am unsure of it will need to be unhidden. I thought the best way to do this was for all users of my app have it set to hidden and then using their user accounts change a boolean from false to true on the day I need it changing. However it could be very tedious to change each individual boolean in the Data Browser. Does anyone know how I could go about setting this? I also had the thought of creating a new class in the data browser and then calling the object from the ID in within the code. However I don't know how to set an ObjectID within the data browser either so if someone could help me with that as well that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change each boolean in the data browser, write a small program that queries the table, changes the booleans, and saves the objects.

Comment: A Job in Cloud Code would be the best way to handle it.

Comment: How does it affect the API call quota? If I have 1 million records, would I consume all the API quota just to change one column in all the rows?

Comment: @RishabhTayal I am not sure about that, actually. That is a good question. There should be something in the parse.com docs about that but I do not know the answer off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: Haha, looks like you still have to run this query 1000 times as parse's object limit is 1000